# Determining mode of operation of BJT

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt

In this first schematic is it cut-off or in forward active when Vbe,on = 0.7V? When I first look at it, i thought it could be in cut-off since when you do KVL at BE junction, Ib = (0-0.7)/10k = -0.07mA wouldnt Ib < 0 make it in cutoff? However, im not sure what effect V2 would have on the circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frkAJN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Moreover, in this second circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEhesF.png)</sup>

In this second circuit, I see that Ib > 0 (by kvl 5-0.7/10k) so the circuit would be either in saturation or in forward active, however Vc would just be 12V right? so it would be in forward active? but when i look at the simulation, i will see that BE and BC junction are both forward biased, making the diagram in saturation, how can i prove mathematically that both BE and BC junction are both forward biased?

Comment: Vbe is only 0.7 when Ib is given positive >> 1mA not 0 V, so this is bad  logic.... Ib = (0-0.7)/10k = -0.07mA, but V2 cannot affect that

Comment: In the first circuit, both the base and emitter are effectively grounded out. The collector is held at +5 V. But no base recombination current is available. The BJT is off and the collector is floating and that's that. In the 2nd diagram, you'll have more than 400 uA of base current. If beta is about 100 (very modest estimate and almost 100% change to be higher than that), then this means about 40 mA of collector current is possible. But 12 V divided by 500 Ohms is only 24 mA. So the BJT is saturated, almost certainly.

Comment: @jonk am i right in my understanding that the current in the collector should equal to BetaIb for it to be in forward active?

Comment: If Vce >= 1V then it is forward active. Below this is a gray area as hFE begins to degrade rapidly then the mean saturation voltage from low to high Ic is about Vce=0.5V at which you can say it is saturated.  Beta or hFE is still Ic/Ib but much less now than what it was at Vce=1V. Often datashhets may show Vce(sat)= Vce for Ic/Ib=10 at 1mA,  10 mA, 100 mA where  Vce rises due to bulk resistance as a switch with this current ratio in saturation.

Comment: For these simple exercises don't rely on simulation but on the equivalent models. Since you are doing biasing (large signal) try using the model corresponding to the model you think it's working in and then verify that the bias condition apply. If you guessed wrong try with another one.

Comment: @AedenSchmidt I don't know if you are right or not. The 2nd circuit is kind of silly anyway because of the direct short across R1. So I don't know why such a circuit was written down in the first place. But the remaining R2 will drop enough voltage to push the collector into saturation.

Comment: @user_1818839  look again Vbe=0